# Need advice tackling many In-App Store products (StoreKit)

Tags: ios, storekit

I'm about to take my first foray into In-App purchases, and I'm not quite sure how to handle my situation. At top is my situation, with some actual questions in bold at the bottom. Any advice would be appreciated.

I'm designing an app that will have a LOT of in-app purchase content. Every day, around 20 or 30 new items will be generated for sale. 3 or 4 days worth of items will be for sale at any given time, and after that they go away.

So we're talking a lot of items. Way too many to add to submit to Apple for a unique ProductID each day.

Of all these hundred items, there are actually only 4 or 5 different types of item. So I'm thinking I'll need to make 1 SKProduct for each type. Under the hood (and invisible to the user) the will actually be buying a credit good for 1 item of type X. After the transaction goes through, I send the receipt AND the requested item to our server. Our server stores that and sends the file back. If they want a 2nd file, they need to buy a 2nd credit and repeat the process. Of course to the user it will be presented like they're buying Item 1, Item 2, and Item 3 directly.

To make this even more complicated, we also want to offer a 3 month subscription (at a significantly higher tier) for those who don't want to buy their items ala carte.

**1. Does this sound like a good approach?** 
Will Apple be okay with this? If not, what possible alternatives do I have?

**2. Optimally we'd like to allow people to re-download items they've already paid for.**
Would a good approach be to make each credit non-consumable, and since I've already stored the receipt info on the server I can match it to whatever item they should get? If this is too complicated or against Apple's rules, we may just make the item consumable since the item is only good for a few days anyway...

**3. Is there anything else I'm overlooking here?**

Thanks for any insight you guys can provide.

Comment: did you publish your app? was there any problem with sections 2.1/2.2 as noted by codingcthulhu?

Comment: Yes we published. No problems w/ the app store.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look about what the iOS Development Program License Agreement says about treating In App Purchases like credits:

> 2.1   You may not use the In App Purchase API to enable an end-user to set up a pre-paid  account to be used for subsequent purchases of
> content, functionality, or services, or otherwise  create balances or
> credits that end-users can redeem or use to make purchases at a later
> time.
>
> 2.2 You may not enable end-users to purchase Currency of any kind through the In App
> Purchase API, including but not limited to any Currency for exchange,
> gifting, redemption,  transfer, trading or use in purchasing or
> obtaining anything within or outside of Your Application.   “Currency”
> means any form of currency, points, credits, resources, content or
> other items or units  recognized by a group of individuals or entities
> as representing a particular value and that can be  transferred or
> circulated as a medium of exchange.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if your approach does not unlock/add  functionality or change the behavior of the app by buying an In App Purchase, my guess is that this could be problematic when trying to get Apple's approval.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Then how do all the freemium games on the AppStore do it then? E.X. Storm8 games, you buy 'points' which you can use in-game.

Comment: I guess that's because it affects the game somehow, you can use them while playing, and also you don't use them like currency, "as a medium of exchange" as the 2.2 states.

Comment: Apps have credits all the time. Hanging/Words/fill-in-the-blank With Friends comes to mind. So does Jetpack Joyride. Infinity Blade does as well. Many games have you buy "300 gold for $.99" that you can then buy with an ingame store. When I read that provision it seems more to me like something to prevent laundering via the app store. It shouldn't be a *currency*...  Plus, as far as the user is concerned they AREN'T purchasing a credit; that part is only behind-the-scenes because I can't have 30 individual products added every day...